# To show dynamic chart from takpane to slide in office PowerPoint add-in?

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

Dynamic chart from takpane should be shown in slide, is this possible in PowerPoint office add-in?

currently chart shown in task pane is by using chart.js and its dynamic,
I have already try using in content add-in. https://prnt.sc/oiq9MxQi3k1X

but I need to show this chart into slide (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz5p4.png)_Rz0LLk)

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that by "dynamic chart" you mean a chart that changes at runtime. I think that the only way to get such a chart into a slide is to create a [content add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/design/content-add-ins) instead of a task pane add-in.

Comment: @RickKirkham,I  have already try this but I need chart on slide not in content add-in. https://prnt.sc/oiq9MxQi3k1X thanks for reply